# Leak Canary - reference stack not showing for a libgdx app

Tags: android, memory-leaks, libgdx, leakcanary

I can see my libgdx based activity is leaking, but I have no idea where it is referenced from.

It seems that LeakCanary doesn't have access to the debug information of the libgdx part of the app (probably since it's built as a separate module in the project).

Attaching a screenshot of the leak dump:
[image: Leak dump]

What can I do to get LeakCanary to know what's going on within the libgdx part of the code?

Answer (score 0):

OK,
It turns out it wasn't a missing stack trace (Gdx.app IS the activity, and is the only reference to it), and it's not an important leak after all.

Once I start a new libgdx activity Gdx.app will be set to it and the old one will be destroyed, so it's not a big deal.

(not deleting the question as others might fear the same leak unjustifiably).